# Bootstrap tagsinput autocomplete doesn't work

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, json, linq, twitter-bootstrap

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(function () {
    $('#input-tagautocomplete').tagsinput({
        typeahead: {
            source: function (term, process) {
                items = [];
                map = {};
                var url = "@Url.Content("~/video/Getchannel/")";
                return $.getJSON(url, { term: term }, function (data) {
                    $.each(data, function (i, item) {
                        map[item.Ch_Name] = item;
                        items.push(item.Ch_Name);

                    });
                    return (items);
                });
            },
            updater: function (item) {
                var selected = map[item].Id;
                alert(selected);
                $('#tag-value').val(selected);
                return item;
            }
        }
    });
});
```

I have this script containing ajax request to get source in array.

Then passing these value in autocomplete.

I am trying to get something like this-

http://jsfiddle.net/Palapas/WtC27/1/

**Note-**
While request of JSON type sent to method, It comes back to me with an array result as it should be in case of autocomplete.

```
public JsonResult Getchannel(string term)
{
    var genes = (from u in tp.Channels
                 where u.Ch_Name.Contains(term)
                 select u).ToArray();
    var result = genes.Select(m => new { Ch_Name = m.Ch_Name, Id = m.Id });

    return new JsonResult()
               {
                   Data = result,
                   JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
               };
}
```

This method returns me array of `Ch_Name` and `Id`.

Then I am selecting only names in display field of input and saving its id when its selected.

But I don't get this autocomplete work.

What am I missing here? I suppose everything is working fine at my end.

**Here is a snapshot of data coming from method-**

[image]

Comment: Try add this before typehead `itemValue: 'Id',
  itemText: 'Ch_Name',`

Comment: @RaúlMonge, That works but only problem is , it is not updated in updater. I am trying to get selected's Id through updater, but that doesn't work.

Answer (score -1):

There is no 'updater' property of the typeahead parameter.

However, you can use `$('#input-tagautocomplete').val()` to get a string containing a comma separated list of tags. See [this page](http://timschlechter.github.io/bootstrap-tagsinput/examples/) for the reference.